# How often did the race occur in Ready Player One?

Tags: ready-player-one-2018

In the movie, *Ready Player One*, how often was the racing contest held? Was this on a schedule, or announced an arbitrary bit of time before it was to start?

Comment: One question per question please. The bit in spoilers is not a natural extension of the rest of your question and would require a separate answer.

Comment: @amflare Sure thing.  My other questions which were distinct but similar were vtc as duplicates, so I was afraid to separate out questions that would be addressed with a single answer.

Comment: We don't know for sure, but presumably it was on a regular basis. I would like to think it was every Saturday or something. Assuming Wade was "in school" (given the movie differences) he would have had to skip on a regular basis to make it; as would everyone else despite work and other responsibilities.

Comment: I am afraid to follow the tag of "ready-player-one-2018" because it did not last long the first time it was around...

Comment: @Quasi_Stomach - Just caught a line in the movie that doesn't answer your question, but makes me rethink my initial assumption. When Wade first contacts Aech in the film he says: "Next race is in 20 minutes and I can't afford to do the late one." This makes me think that the race was announced before hand, but at random days/times. Otherwise, why would Wade need to inform Aech when the race was starting? Also, why would Wade not have made sure his car was fueled up prior to the race start or known before hand he needed to skim coins for gas?

Answer (score -5):

In the book it was held at regular intervals. Ranking (starting position) was based on the amount of game wealth possessed.

Comment: Adding supporting information, like a quote, would improve this.

Comment: What book? There was no race in the novel written by Ernest Cline the film is based on...

Comment: Also, keep in mind the question was specifically asking about the movie.